# Set frame size image inside UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an image size : `CGRectMake(100,70,50,50)` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I need to change the frame size image when the cells is odd

Code is:

```
if(indexPath.row %2)
{
  CGRectMake(200,70,50,50)
}
else
{
  CGRectMake(100,70,50,50)
}
```

In the first time when I load `TableView`, it's work ok, but when I scroll again and again, the frame size image display is in the wrong position. It changes very funny, I don't know why.

Can you help me

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you're not setting the resulting frame from your CGRectMake call to anything...

Comment: @Bruno Koga: What i will do? How?

Answer (score 0):

You have set set the frame on your `UIImageView` subview:

```
if(indexPath.row %2) {
    cell.yourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(200,70,50,50)
} else {
    cell.yourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(100,70,50,50)
}
```

Comment: I'm using storyboard, if I use to subview inside UITableView, when i scroll uitableview, imageview have add to subview, imageview is override

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following way.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UIImageView * imageView;
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if(indexpath.row%2 == 0)
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 70, 50, 50)];
    else
    {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 70, 50, 50)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.tag=11;
        [imageView release];
    }
}
else
    {
        imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];
    }
// here are couple of other statements 
    ...............
}
```

Comment: thank you, i'm using Fix cell from Storyboard. Have you solution don't use Cell from UITableCell

Comment: Even though you scroll again and again this code will display UIImageview in correct position.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create a custom table cell and do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
     ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
     [cell configureWithRow:indexPath.row];
 }
```

Then in your custom table cell, create an IBOutlet for your resizable image view and add a method:

```
-(void)configureWithRow:(NSInteger)row
{
    if(indexPath.row %2) 
   {
        self.resizableImageView.frame = CGRectMake(200,70,50,50)
   } 
   else 
   {
       cell.resizableImageView.frame = CGRectMake(100,70,50,50)
    }
}
```

This does a couple of things

1. You don't have to check for a nil cell because you are guaranteed to get a cell back dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier as long as the identifier matches one in your storyboard and your view controller is a UITableViewController.
2. You move the logic for the configuration of the cell to the custom table view cell, which is where it really should be. The view controller shouldn't care about the size of the image in the cell.

Comment: I don't understand you, in function configureWithRow I don't get "cell.resizableImageView.frame"